# Flip Alternate Elements in a List ML

Tags: sml, smlnj, ml

I have written a function that will flip alternate elements in a list, however I have to call it, then call its methods (I'm new to ML so I apologize if I'm using the incorrect terms). I would prefer to just call the function without having to call the methods inside it. This is what I have to do now:

```
(*3. Flip alternate elements in a list, if n = odd, element n remains at end*)
fun flip nil x = x
  | flip x nil = x
  | flip (x::xs) (y::ys) = x::y::flip xs ys;

fun take l =
    if l = nil then nil
    else hd l::skip (tl l)

and skip l =
    if l = nil then nil
    else take (tl l);
```

but when I call it to reverse the elements, I have to call it :

```
flip (skip d) (take d);
flip (skip e) (take e);
```

Is there any way to call the function as :

```
flip (d);
```

If I call `flip (d);` now, it just prints

```
val take = fn : ''a list -> ''a list
val skip = fn : ''a list -> ''a list
```

Thank you all in advance!

EDIT: I should mention d is just a list of ints:

```
val d = [1,2,3,4];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming "flipping alternate elements in a list" means turning `[1,2,3,4,5,6]` into `[2,1,4,3,6,5]`, and throwing away the last element if the length is odd, then you can achieve this simply by pattern matching in a single function:

```
fun flip (x::y::xs) = y::x::flip xs
  | flip _ = []
```

Some feedback on your code snippets:

- Many of your parentheses are unnecessary.
- Don't use `hd` / `tl`, but rather use pattern matching.
- The actual flipping takes place in your `take` and `skip`.

  Your `flip` could appropriately be called `merge`.
- If this were the case, in order to fix `flip` so it only takes one argument:

  ```
  fun flip xs = merge (skip xs) (take xs)
  ```

  It is very useful to be able to make helper functions with more arguments and call these.

Comment: Thank you, this is pretty much exactly what I was looking for!